# Using quotes and variables in PHP - issues with image uri and variable in an echo function

Tags: php, css, html-email

The PHP dev I'm working with has this code to generate X number of images in an email -

```
         <?php
            foreach ($viewerPhotos as $photo) {
                echo sprintf('<div style="$photoBgCss"><img src="%s" style="border:0;vertical-align: middle;" alt="User photo" width="77" height="77" border="0" /></div>', $photo);
            }
         ?>
```

I added the div around the image and the style attribute. The styles associated with $photoBgCss are -

```
$photoBgCss = "background-image: url('$staticUrl/images/general/email/photo-bg.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 0 0;
        display:inline-block;
        margin-right:1%;
        padding: 6px 0 15px 0;
        text-align: center;
        width: 89px;";
```

When I send myself a test email, the background image doesn't parse. I know this has something to do with quotes and/or the (). I've tried several approaches but haven't found a solution. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I mentioned this is a comment below, but it will be more readable here... I tried adding the background image inline on the div but still had problems -

```
echo sprintf('<div style="background-image: url('$staticUrl/images/general/email/one-photo-bg.png');"><img src="%s" style="border:0;vertical-align: middle;" alt="User photo" width="77" height="77" border="0" /></div>', $photo);
```

Comment: You're missing a < at the beginning of the string

Comment: Interesting use of sprintf in that loop. Anyway, that line is wrong, it won't replace $photoBgCss with the content of your variable. As Barbara said, it's invalid HTML as well.

Comment: Barbara, thanks for the catch. I corrected that. 

Now, I also tried adding the background inline like this and still had trouble -

echo sprintf('<div style="background-image: url('$staticUrl/images/general/email/one-photo-bg.png');"><img src="%s" style="border:0;vertical-align: middle;" alt="User photo" width="77" height="77" border="0" /></div>', $photo);

Answer (score 0):

You missed a <

```
     <?php
        foreach ($viewerPhotos as $photo) {
            echo sprintf('div style="$photoBgCss"><img src="%s" style="border:0;vertical-align: middle;" alt="User photo" width="77" height="77" border="0" /></div>', $photo);
           // Right here ^
        }
     ?>
```

Check:

```
     <?php
        foreach ($viewerPhotos as $photo) {
            echo sprintf('<div style="$photoBgCss"><img src="%s" style="border:0;vertical-align: middle;" alt="User photo" width="77" height="77" border="0" /></div>', $photo);
        }
     ?>
```

And for this:

```
$photoBgCss = "background-image: url('$staticUrl/images/general/email/photo-bg.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:1%;
    padding: 6px 0 15px 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 89px;";
```

I prefer:

```
$photoBgCss = "background-image: url('" . $staticUrl . "/images/general/email/photo-bg.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:1%;
    padding: 6px 0 15px 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 89px;";
```